# Analysis- subspaces from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector subspace such that $E\neq \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $\text{int}(E)=\emptyset$, where $E$ is a closed and connected set.

I don't know how to solve, someone can help me, any tips?

Comment: What kind of subspace?  Topological?  Vector?  Topological-vector?

Comment: @Randall Probably just vector.

Comment: @Randall Vector subspace

Answer (score 0):

$0\notin Int(E)$ because if there exists a open ball $B(0,\epsilon) $ such that it is contained in $E$ then $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ because  for each $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$  then $\frac{\epsilon}{||v||}v$ is in $B(0,\epsilon)\subseteq E$ but $E$ is a subspace so $\frac{||v||}{\epsilon} (\frac{\epsilon}{||v||}v)=v\in E$. 
Each point of $E$ can be mapped in $0$ with a translation so each point it is in $int(E)$ if and only if $0\in \phi(E)=E$ but it is not possibile

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you talk about vector subspace and the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is induced by the usual (Euclidean) norm $\left| \left| \cdot \right| \right|$.

Now, since $E$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space, it must be finite dimensional. Say $\left\lbrace v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_m \right\rbrace$ is a basis for $E$. We can extend this basis to $\left\lbrace v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_m, v_{m + 1}, \cdots, v_n \right\rbrace$ to be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $E \neq \mathbb{R}^n$, clearly $m \neq n$ and in particular $v_n \notin \left\lbrace v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_m \right\rbrace$.

We shall assume that these bases are normalised, i.e., $\left| \left| v_i \right| \right| 
= 1$ for every $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$.

Now, let $x \in E$ be any vector. Construct an open ball $B \left( x, \epsilon \right)$. The vector $x + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} v_n \in B \left( x, \epsilon \right)$ since $\left| \left| x - \left( x + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} v_n \right) \right| \right| = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$ however, $x + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} v_n \notin E$ since it cannot be written as a linear combination of elements $\left\lbrace v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_m \right\rbrace$. This is because of the linear independence of a basis.

Therefore, taken any point in $E$ and constructing any open ball around it, that open ball is not contained in $E$. Hence, no point of $E$ can be interior point, i.e., $\text{int} \left( E \right) = \emptyset$.